# Special unofficial nationwide vote/poll in 1994 in the United States of America

Tags: united-states, voting, immigration

In 1994 (+/- 1 year) in the United States of America the was some special public vote. The vote itself was related to some agreement made by a smaller group of politicians.

I believe it began as something unofficial, then they tried to make it official, then they disqualified the original results, then I don't know if anything further happened.

In my limited understanding, this pertained to the either the number of immigrants per year and/or the proportions or limits in the mix of nations that were allowed.

A group of people were discussing this recently and my 5th grade teacher reminded me that she explained it to me back when it happened. She said that the Supreme Court struck down the validity of the vote and the Republicans wanted a "do over" but it never happened, but even if the vote had passed it's unclear that it could've struck down the deal made by the small group of elected representatives.

They said the small group that enacted whatever decision was made, which the special vote was a mostly-Republican attempt to counter, had previously been tried and failed. They said that the original attempt to do it had been blocked, by virtue of not having enough power by not involving any Republicans.

Does anyone have any specific names, dates, or info on these events?

Comment: FWIW, I was a registered voter in law school at the time in Michigan and I can assure you that no such nationwide vote occurred.

Comment: There are no national votes in the USA. There are votes in each state. For example, people don't vote for president in a national election. The president is chosen by 50 statewide elections. So I don't see how your scenario would be possible.

Comment: My understanding is that after the poll/vote censorship began/increased pertaining to the topic, which is why I think it's hard to find info...

Comment: You think a nationwide vote in the USA in 1994 is being hidden from the public by censorship?

Comment: @Michael_B I do until I find it (this is a half-joke). Asides from everyone I knew who was an adult, the people telling me this recently were government (IC). I think it's not totally censored but it's the type of thing that is probably titled in a misleading way and they may or may not suppress social media postings on it.

Comment: Please read my first comment again. Also, 1994 was a big election year (Newt Gingrich, "Contract With America", House went to the GOP for the first time in 4 decades). I remember it well. I don't recall any nationwide vote about immigration.

Comment: @Hack-R - Why don't you ask your parents (or former teacher) for more specifics?  There is _no_ legal way to have a nationwide vote or referendum, so the default assumption should be that it didn't happen.

Comment: @Bobson I know with 100% certainty that it happened, but I do remember them saying that it was non-standard in that way so it had a special legal status and plan around it to get the Supreme court to accept it. I can't ask my parents they are no longer in my life since we differ on this topic.

Comment: @Michael_B That it happened is not in question, but it was not through the normal legal methods I think (see my prior comment to Bob).

Comment: @Hack-R If you insist it happened, and don't have anyone you can ask about it, then really the only thing you can do is go through the front page of every single day's newspaper until you either find it or conclude it didn't happen as you remember.    [Here's the main Atlanta paper's archive](https://ajc.newspapers.com/browse/The%20Atlanta%20Constitution_406/1994/01/01) - it's a paid service, but it has a week free trial, which should be long enough to check every day. _Even if_ the internet is being censored, there's no good way to change archival images of newspaper headlines.

Comment: @Hack-R: I was an adult in 1994, and active in politics.  (That might even have been the year that I got talked into running for office...)  Unless the people doing the censoring have figured out how to do a memory wipe, there absolutely was not any sort of nationwide referendum on ANYTHING, and no special public vote.  There was nothing on the Nevada ballot remotely resembling what you describe: https://ballotpedia.org/Nevada_1994_ballot_measures

Answer (score 5):

The US Constitution does not provide for a nationwide referendum, and there has accordingly not been such a vote.

The closest thing I can find to what you described is a 1994 ballot initiative in California, known as Proposition 187, which would have effectively denied all public services (including health care and education) to those who were not in the US lawfully.  The proposition was ruled unconstitutional by the Supreme Court, on the grounds that immigration is a federal matter, not a state matter.

Comment: Thank you, but this was also voted on by my parents and teachers in Georgia. My understanding is that after the vote censorship began/increased pertaining to the topic, which is why I think it's hard to find info...

Comment: There were several ballot initiatives in Georgia in 1994 (https://ballotpedia.org/Georgia_1994_ballot_measures).  I can't find anything like you're describing, either in that year or any other year in the 1990s.

Comment: Interesting, maybe that's what it was. I will check.

Comment: "The proposition was ruled unconstitutional by the Supreme Court" Actually, it was only ruled unconstitutional by a federal district court. The new Democratic governor halted appeals of it beyond that.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this was [California Proposition 187](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_California_Proposition_187) in 1994.

> California Proposition 187 (also known as the Save Our State (SOS) initiative) was a 1994 ballot initiative to establish a state-run citizenship screening system and prohibit illegal immigrants from using non-emergency health care, public education, and other services in the State of California. Voters passed the proposed law at a referendum on November 8, 1994. The law was challenged in a legal suit the day after its passage, and found unconstitutional by a federal district court on November 11th. In 1999, Governor Gray Davis halted state appeals of this ruling.

Comment: Thank you, but this was also voted on by my parents and teachers in Georgia

Comment: Another thought, this is unlikely but, perhaps this was a proxy for some further reaching political action (via loopholes?) and perhaps other states were trying to do similar things?